# Build a DLL with all packages included

Tags: dll, c++builder

In BDS 4.0 I've build a VC-Style DLL, I want that this DLL includes all packages in order to be independant as well, I can use it and deploy it even on PC that haven't the Borland RTL installed.

(I've BDS in a Virtual Machine and VC++ on my host computer).

So, I modified compiling options like this:

- Uncheck the use of dynamic RTL
- Check "Build with execution packages:" and list all packages that I want to include (rtl, vcl, ...).

But when using this DLL in VC++, `LoadLibrary` fails and ask to me to add rtl100.bpl, vcl100.bpl, ... in the package.

If I copy all BPL that are on my virtual machine to my host computer, `LoadLibrary` works.

How can I include all these packages in my C++Builder DLL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have uncorrectly checked "Build with execution packages" option. When it's checked, all listed packages are linked dynamically so you'll need to distribute *.bpl files with your application. If you uncheck this option, all packages will be statically linked into your dll